# Не запускается скомпилированный JAVA файл

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

Хочу опробовать библиотеку  jssc для работы с COM портом. После импортированния в Eclipse, тестовый код запускается

```
import jssc.SerialPortList;
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
    for(int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
        System.out.println(portNames[i]);      
    }
}
}
```

Но при попытке запустить из командной строки скомпилированный test.class, выдает ошибку:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  jssc/SerialPortList
    at test.main(test.java:8)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jssc.SerialPortList
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Пробовал помещать "jssc.jar" непосредственно в "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin", но это не помогает. С джавой, только начинаю работать, по этому прошу вашей помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависимости должны быть доступны в [CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html)

```
java -cp .;jssc.jar test
```

Comment: Работает. Но хотел запустить на Raspberry Linux и выдало в консоль Error: -cp requires class path specification, хотя jssc рядом с моей программой

Comment: На LINUX нужно заменить ; на : и все заработает)